# How to make visible hidden controls?

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic controls and have data on it, Below is the code of dynamic controls:

```
<% @user_education.each do |user_edu| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[value='ADD']").click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                //var field = $("#field").val();
                var tb_fromEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

                var tb_ToEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


                var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
                + tb_fromEducation + " to " + tb_ToEducation + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
                newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


                var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
                $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);
            });

            $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
                var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
                $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
                return false;
            });


        });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

These controls are hidden, only html button is visible i.e below:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <table id="SchoolControls" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            </table>
            <table id="ControlsSch" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            </table>
            <input id="AddSch" type="button" value="ADD" />
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

It shows me the controls when I click on an html button "ADD". And I want that without clicking on button the controls should be visible. Kindly help me. Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot of HTML to be parsing to the document... did you write the above code...?

Comment: No i wrote the code ,I am his codeveloper

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to accomplish. `ADD` and `REMOVE` both work... See here(http://jsfiddle.net/K2J8u/)

Comment: remove this code '$("input[value='ADD']").click(function(e)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `click` event:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {


  $("input[value='ADD']").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            //var field = $("#field").val();
            var tb_fromEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

            var tb_ToEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


            var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
            + tb_fromEducation + " to " + tb_ToEducation + "</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
            newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


            var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
            var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
            $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
            $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);
        });

        $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
            var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
            $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
            return false;
        });




            //var field = $("#field").val();
            var tb_fromEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersFromSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolFrom %>' />";

            var tb_ToEducation = "<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='ParametersToSch' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolTo %>' />";


            var newRow1 = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' >"
            + tb_fromEducation + " to " + tb_ToEducation + "</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' >"
            newRow1 += "<input type='button' class='btn_rmvsch' value='Remove'/></td></tr>";


            var input1 = "<input name='parametersSch' id='field' type='text' value='<%= user_edu.SchoolName %>' />"
            var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' >" + input1 + "</td></tr>";
            $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow);
            $('#ControlsSch').append(newRow1);


        $('#ControlsSch').on('click', '.btn_rmvsch', function() {
            var index = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 2
            $('#ControlsSch tr:nth-child(n+' + (index - 3) + ')').remove();
            return false;
        });


    });
```

//Check New fiddle with Add event

http://jsfiddle.net/4hmhr/

I forgot to Add jQuery library,You better add it from left side

UPDATED FIDDLE INCLUDING JQUERY 
http://jsfiddle.net/mEUed/

Comment: Its good, but html "ADD" is not working, and I want to add more controls to add information of user

Comment: You guys are on your own here. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I forgot to Add jQuery library,You better add it from left side in JSFiddle

Comment: @Pratik Joshi: Its working, but would not show me controls and data on it, it hides the control, only add button is visible.

Comment: I told you add library in jsFiddle from left panel